# Detect Category of Chart

Tags: pine-script

There is any way to detect if you are looking to a forex or crypto or stock for exemple i want to change some variables on my calculations if im looking in a crypto chart but totally different values if it is a forex chart

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`syminfo.type` will return as a string the type of the current symbol

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_syminfo{dot}type](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dtype)